# Format DateTime object in Model as NotMapped Property

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, model

I have a model called `Report` having bellow two properties. I am going to retrieve the data and send it to jQuery datatable. I need to format the date field before sending it to view, I did it as bellow:

```
public class Report
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime ActivityDate { get; set; }

    //Here is the date formation property
    public string FormattedDate => ActivityDate.ToString();
}
```

Here is the action method which is being called by jQuery datatable:

```
[JQDataTable]
public ActionResult Search()
{
     IQueryable<Report> data = db.Reports;
     return View("Index",data);
}
```

The problem is, I can not get the formatted date, instead I am getting an error of:

```
The specified type member 'FormattedDate' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

I tried and search alot but was unable to find a solution for this. In next step I want to convert this date to `PersianCalendar` object and return its string.

Comment: it's generally deemed good practice any way to use viewmodels to represent only what data your view needs. this would solve your issue since you would query out the raw reports and then your reportviewmodel would have the `FormattedDate`. at the time of conversion from raw model to view model linq to entities would no longer be a factor.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar problems using ToString inside Linq query. For your case I think it would be easier to handle the conversion of datetime in time of view and leave the datetime variable as is. Rather accept specific format for the search action, parse the received date and do the query.

After suffering for a very long time, I now tend to accept datetime from view as string with my explicitly specified format ("yyyy-mm-dd" just my personal choice :P ) and use DateTime.TryParseExact() handling the null input as well.

Hope it helps. Happy coding.